# How Many MB's can an intro movie be for an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, movieclip

In my app i want to play a short movie I have one (4.4 Mb mp4) but I receive a memory warning level 1 On the debug console.

when I remove it no memory warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the memory warning otherwise your application may be forcefully killed.
Each active view controller receives the message and you can handle it in the function `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning`

There is no limit on the size of the application or any other asset its using. However on getting the memory warning you need to handle and release all the unwanted resource files before the application is made to forcefully exit.

Comment: I handle and release all the unwanted resource files but only I receive the warning in case the movie is playing

Comment: In the case where you are handling the memory warnings then there is very little you can do about this. I have read with large files there always seem to be problems. Does the warning appear from second time of play?

Comment: If so then you have to properly release the cache of the movie player controller.

Comment: the warning appear from the first time of play

Comment: Did you check for possible memory leaks using analyser?